# ICE failed for component 1 in stream

Tags: websocket, video-streaming, webrtc, janus, janus-gateway

I have configured **janus** server for video call.
configured all setups and installed all dependencies as per the [Docs](https://github.com/meetecho/janus-gateway)

successfully established the connection but unable to stream the video. After starts the new session ICE failed error throws error logs as follows

JANUS WebSockets transport plugin initialized!
WebSockets thread started
Creating new session: 7153905178555544; 0x7fd244004c00
Creating new handle in session 7153905178555544: 7459090747208459; 0x7fd244004c00 0x7fd244005670
Creating new session: 8203604816882479; 0x7fd24400b8c0
Creating new handle in session 8203604816882479: 1196748959220562; 0x7fd24400b8c0 0x7fd244018910
Destroying session 8203604816882479; 0x7fd24400b8c0
Detaching handle from JANUS VideoRoom plugin; 0x7fd244018910 0x7fd24400b890 0x7fd244018910 0x7fd24401f760
[janus.plugin.videoroom-0x7fd24400b890] No WebRTC media anymore; 0x7fd244018910 0x7fd24401f760
[1196748959220562] Handle and related resources freed; 0x7fd244018910 0x7fd24400b8c0
[WSS-0x7fd244008340] Destroying WebSocket client
[7459090747208459] Creating ICE agent (ICE Lite mode, controlled)

[WARN] [7459090747208459] ICE failed for component 1 in stream 1, but let's give it some time... (trickle received, answer received, alert not set)

**[ERR] [ice.c:janus_ice_check_failed:1692] [7459090747208459] ICE failed for component 1 in stream 1..**.
[janus.plugin.videoroom-0x7fd244001e60] No WebRTC media anymore; 0x7fd244005670 0x7fd244005fe0
[7459090747208459] WebRTC resources freed; 0x7fd244005670 0x7fd244004c00
[ERR] [transports/janus_http.c:janus_http_handler:1239] Invalid url /ws/v1/cluster/apps/new-application
[ERR] [transports/janus_http.c:janus_http_handler:1239] Invalid url /ws/v1/cluster/apps/new-application
[ERR] [transports/janus_http.c:janus_http_handler:1239] Invalid url /ws/v1/cluster/apps/new-application
[ERR] [transports/janus_http.c:janus_http_handler:1239] Invalid url /ws/v1/cluster/apps/new-application
[ERR] [transports/janus_http.c:janus_http_handler:1239] Invalid url /ws/v1/cluster/apps/new-application
[ERR] [transports/janus_http.c:janus_http_handler:1239] Invalid url /ws/v1/cluster/apps/new-applicatio

Answer (score 2):

You can speicfy stun/turn servers for icing in /opt/janus/etc/janus/janus.jcfg.
Also you should open ports for udp like 40000-65535

Comment: just want to add that on top of this, I had to set the nat_1_to_1 (or something) to my external ip when using a VM/cloud service.